# JWT authentication in vertx throwing unauthorized

Tags: java, reactjs, jwt, keycloak, vert.x

In my application, i'm using react with keycloak authentication. And i'm trying to secure my back end vertx APIs using the received token from keycloak.
I followed this blog http://paulbakker.io/java/jwt-keycloak-angular2/

i'm calling like this from react

```
    return await fetch('/api/getAuthentication',{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {"Authorization" : `Bearer ${token}`}
        })
}
```

And in my vertx side

```
JsonObject authConfig = new JsonObject()
                    .put("public-key", "MyPublicKeyFromKeycloak")
                    .put("permissionsClaimKey", "realm_access/roles");        
            JWTAuth authProvider = JWTAuth.create(vertx, new JWTAuthOptions(authConfig));
            router.route("/api/*").handler(JWTAuthHandler.create(authProvider));
```

And I tried to test with below code,

```
router.route("/api/getAuthentication").handler(ctx -> {
                logger.info("Headers: {}", ctx.request().headers().get("Authorization"));
                logger.info(ctx.user().principal().encodePrettily());
            });
```

I cannot see any log,in my browser the response is "unauthorized" with 401 code.

Comment: you have to `end()` the RequestContext in your handler somewhere. Otherwise it won't be sent back

Comment: @injecteer,Its not entering into "/api/getAuthentication" handler.I tried end() already, still same,that is why i cannot see any logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, `JWTAuthOptions` will do nothing with what you have set under key `"public-key"` as it does not have any property that maps to it (even if it was possible in Java to have a `-` in property names). So either set your values on `JWTAuthOptions` directly using setters or consult [documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-auth-jwt/java/) for proper keys.

Second, if your Keycloak is setup with OIDC, then you can simply use `OpenIDConnectAuth` class that discovers the necessary parameters from Keycloak automatically. Which is way easier.

Comment: ,Thank you so much. I tried the first option and it is working as expected